# Convert map to a sorted list

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a map...

```
Map(a -> List(a, a), b -> List(b, b), l -> List(l, l))
```

I can convert to a List

```
List((a,2), (l,2), (b,2))
```

By simply doing `myMap.toList();`

But I'd like to convert to a sorted list - which sorted on the first element of the tuple?

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: can't you convert a map to a sorted map first?

Answer (score 11):

Quick solution: `myMap.toList.sortBy(_._1)`.

This is equivalent to `myMap.toList.sortBy(tuple => tuple._1)`. The `_1` gets first element from a tuple.

`sortBy` in general takes a function that maps sorted elements to some value and that value will be used to compare elements being sorted.

You can also write this more verbosely like this: `myMap.toList.sortBy {case (key, _) => key}`

Comment: what about the efficiency of that thou as you convert to the list and then go thru every element in the list?

Comment: Can you explain what the short _._1 means? Is it for every element compare by the first element in the tuple?

Comment: @MoreThanFive If you want to use `List` which is immutable, then I don't see how this can be more efficient (in terms of complexity and amount of copying).

Comment: If you want to avoid extra CPU cycles you could use from the beginning a ListMap and order when inserting instead of creating the structure and order at the end. But if this is a short map is some kind of overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, it may be appropriate to use an ordered collection in the first place.

A **TreeMap** is a SortedMap -- it keeps the collection sorted as you insert/remove values, providing logarithmic lookup/insertion. If your sort operation happens frequently relative to insertion/removal, it may be worth trading off the constant time operations to have cheap access to sorted results.

A **ListMap** is a list-based map structure. Lookup/insertion are horribly inefficient, but this may be an appropriate choice if these operations happen relatively infrequently. You'll have to sort the list whenever you insert pairs.